# grails where should I put a test for a Java class in src/java?

Tags: grails

I have a Java class in src/java whose .class file will be copied to an 'externalConfig' folder and saved in SVN, so that it can be pulled out on the build server and sent to a remote platform. I'm using GGTS 3.1.

I have written a test for this. Where should I put it? I've tried in a xxx.yyy.test package in src/java. I can run this OK as jUnit Test (after putting Mockito in a lib folder and adding to project's classpath).

However, test-app produces compile errors for the test class as it can't find Mockito.*, mock etc. Same result for run-app.

I have refactored and moved the text package and class to test/unit (more in hope than expectation). I got the same errors running test-app, but not from run-app.

Basically, I would be happy for Grails to ignore this test class. What's the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should put them in test/unit or test/integration.
Probably compiled classes are still there in target folder, after you moved them from src to test, call grails clean to remove compiled files.